# Цикл проверки входа бота на сайт

Tags: python, циклы, while

Лучше названия пока не придумал)).

Есть код в нём функции `login()` и `profile()`. Первая отвечает за авторизацию бота на сайт, вторая отправляет на страницу Профиля. На самом сайте я взял тэг, за который можно зацепиться при проверке авторизации. Что-то типа, если `BS4` найдёт это на странице - значит бот не авторизован.

```
if unlog:
   print("Идёт вход в систему...")
   login() #По идее вызывает функцию авторизации
else:
   print("Бот успешно зашёл на сайт")
```

Хочу попросить совета. Как мне сделать цикл, чтобы код возвращался к проверке наличия `unlog`. И в случае его отсутствия пропускал этот блок кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
while True:
    if unlog:
        print("Идёт вход в систему...")
        login() #По идее вызывает функцию авторизации
        continue
    else:
       print("Бот успешно зашёл на сайт")
       break
```